# Does C# allocate Array of Structs as Structure of Arrays in memory?

Tags: c#, performance, compiler-optimization

I am wondering if there is any difference in these 2 constructions in memory when writing c#?

I have made an example and both constructions run at the same speed.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            enArr[i].h = random.Next(0, 1000);
            enArr[i].w = random.Next(0, 1000);

            enArr[i].sum = Math.Sqrt(enArr[i].h)
                + Math.Sqrt(enArr[i].w);

            Console.WriteLine($"AoS Sqr[{i}]: {enArr[i].sum}");
        }
```

vs

```
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            entities.h[i] = random.Next(0, 1000);
            entities.w[i] = random.Next(0, 1000);

            entities.sum[i] = Math.Sqrt(entities.h[i])
                + Math.Sqrt(entities.w[i]);
            Console.WriteLine($"SoA Sqr[{i}]: {entities.sum[i]}");
        }
```

I expected the last one to be faster since SoA gives contiguous data layout, but performs the exact same.

Comment: The processor caches are smart enough to cache multiple memory locations.  Google "4-way associative cache" to learn more.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, thanks, will do, but why is there a difference in c++ then? If you look on youtube (AoS vs SoA) people say that the memory layout is different and leads to a boost in performance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to visit youtube to look at people.  There are plenty of caching hazards around that can cause code to run slower, no matter what language you use.  You have much less insight in such hazards in C# because you know very little about memory layout.  It is unknowable with a garbage collector.  That of course doesn't mean that it will always be "bad" in C#, you have to be unlucky.  The garbage collector in fact tends to provide much more luck, the C++ people have no practical way to compact memory.

Comment: When you say "performances the exact same", do you mean the two methods perform exactly the same. It could just be that the real thing you are measuring is Console.WriteLine. If you are interested in how memory layout affects performance, you should start at researching CPU architecture rather than profiling C# code. Beneath C#, there are many layers intelligent code affecting performance(e.g. compiling, jit, memory paging, CPU caching, pre-fetching, ...).

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, my initial thought was that it has something to do with the garbage collector. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @XiaoguoGe Yeah thanks, I should probably check if Console.Writeline is a factor.